# Does CockroachDB support JSON?

Tags: cockroachdb

I’m interested in trying out CockroachDB, but typically SQL databases don’t natively support JSON. Is there a way for me to access fields of JSON objects in queries if I store them in CockroachDB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UPDATE: CockroachDB supports JSON now.

[Be Flexible & Consistent: JSON Comes to CockroachDB](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/json-coming-to-cockroach/)

> We are excited to announce support for JSON in our 2.0 release (coming in April) and available now via our most recent 2.0 Beta release. Now you can use both structured and semi-structured data within the same database.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

CockroachDB supports JSON. It stores JSON data in `JSONB` data type - Binary JSON.

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table1 (
  id   INT PRIMARY KEY,
  data JSONB
);
```

The size of a `JSONB` field is variable but should be kept within 1 MB to ensure satisfactory performance.

We can insert JSON string as follows:

```sql
INSERT INTO my_table1 (id, data)
VALUES 
    (1, '{"name": "Mary", "age": 16, "city": "Singapore"}'::JSONB),
    (2, '{"name": "John", "age": 17, "city": "Malaysia" }'::JSONB),
    (3, '{"name": "Pete", "age": 18, "city": "Vienna"   }'::JSONB),
    (99,'{"name": "Anna", "gender": "Female"            }'::JSONB);
```

```sql
SELECT * from my_table1;
```

```
  id |                       data
-----+---------------------------------------------------
   1 | {"age": 16, "city": "Singapore", "name": "Mary"}
   2 | {"age": 17, "city": "Malaysia", "name": "John"}
   3 | {"age": 18, "city": "Vienna", "name": "Pete"}
  99 | {"gender": "Female", "name": "Anna"}
(4 rows)
```

#### Return rows (and returning `data` as `JSONB`)

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE data->'age' = '17'::JSONB;
```

```
  id |                      data
-----+--------------------------------------------------
   2 | {"age": 17, "city": "Malaysia", "name": "John"}
(1 row)
```

#### Return rows (and returning `data` as string)

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE data->>'age' = '17';
```

```
  id |                      data
-----+--------------------------------------------------
   2 | {"age": 17, "city": "Malaysia", "name": "John"}
(1 row)
```

#### Return rows showing `age` and `city` from `data` field as `JSONB`

```sql
SELECT id,
       data->'age'  AS "age",
       data->'city' AS "city"
  FROM my_table1;
```

```
  id | age  |    city
-----+------+--------------
   1 |   16 | "Singapore"
   2 |   17 | "Malaysia"
   3 |   18 | "Vienna"
  99 | NULL | NULL
(4 rows)
```

#### Return rows if `data` field has `age` subfield

```sql
SELECT id,
       data->'age'  AS "age",
       data->'city' AS "city"
  FROM my_table1
 WHERE data ? 'age';
```

```
  id | Age |    City
-----+-----+--------------
   1 |  16 | "Singapore"
   2 |  17 | "Malaysia"
   3 |  18 | "Vienna"
(3 rows)
```

#### Return rows if `age` subfield (as string) is equal to `17`

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE data->>'age' = '17';
```

```
  id |                      data
-----+--------------------------------------------------
   2 | {"age": 17, "city": "Malaysia", "name": "John"}
(1 row)
```

#### Return rows if `age` subfield (as `JSONB`) is equal to `17`

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE data->'age' = '17'::JSONB;
```

```
  id |                      data
-----+--------------------------------------------------
   2 | {"age": 17, "city": "Malaysia", "name": "John"}
(1 row)
```

#### Select rows if `name` and `gender` subfields exist in the `data` field.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE data ?& ARRAY['name', 'gender'];
```

```
  id |                 data
-----+---------------------------------------
  99 | {"gender": "Female", "name": "Anna"}
(1 row)
```